# Recordset connection error with .csv file

Tags: excel, vba, csv, adodb

I'm trying to join two CSV files.
Currently I'm trying to add the following code. I added a validation if the connection was open with the "If Not objConnection Is Nothing Then" but supposedly the connection is open. When I run the code I get the following error message:

[image: error msg]

which roughly translates to:
*An error has occurred '2147217904 (80040e10)' in execution time:

Some required values have not been specified.*

I have the following libraries loaded:

[image: references]

The code is as follows:

```
Dim objConnection As ADODB.Connection
Dim objrecordset As ADODB.Recordset


fNameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="CSV File (*.csv),(*.csv)", Title:="Select first CSV file")
If fNameAndPath = False Then
    Exit Sub
End If

fNameAndPath2 = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="CSV File (*.csv),(*.csv)", Title:="Select second CSV file")
If fNameAndPath2 = False Then
    Exit Sub
End If

Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objrecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

strPath = Left(fNameAndPath, InStrRev(fNameAndPath, "\") - 1)
Filename = Mid(fNameAndPath, InStrRev(fNameAndPath, "\") + 1)

strPath2 = Left(fNameAndPath2, InStrRev(fNameAndPath2, "\") - 1)
Filename2 = Mid(fNameAndPath2, InStrRev(fNameAndPath2, "\") + 1)

    With objConnection
        .Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
        .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & strPath & _
        ";Extended Properties=""text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited"";"
        .Open
    End With

    strSql = "SELECT * FROM " & Filename & " as file1, " _
            & "" & Filename2 & " as file2" _
            & " WHERE file1.[APOYO] = file2.[APOYO]"


If Not objConnection Is Nothing Then
    If (objConnection.State And adStateOpen) = adStateOpen Then
        Set objrecordset = objConnection.Execute(strSql)


    End If
End If
```

Comment: You need to open a select statement, execute INSERT/UPDATE etc  set objRS = new adodb.recordset:objRS.open strSQL,objConn

Comment: Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objrecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
 this can be done by set x=new y, you've set the type already

Comment: thanks! i've also tried the Open approach

Comment: have you tried ado 2.8?  I think you may need to have your file name in ' like 'c:\test\test.xls'!DataSheet, so the sheet is acting like a table in convetional select * from myexcel.  I also remember a dollar prefix on the sheet..... look at www.connectionstrings.com

Comment: yup tried it. and its a CSV file and not an xlsx or xls

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974559.aspx have you looked at this?  It looks like you need to leave the \ on the path, also they use .Open and some extra params.

Comment: tried keeping the last \  
then changed the connection part back to de msdn in the link described.

    objConnection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
          "Data Source=" & strPath & ";" & _
          "Extended Properties=""text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited"";"
    
still no go

Answer (score 0):

Restarted from scratch.

This code works:

```
Sub leerCSV()


On Error Resume Next
Const adOpenStatic = 3
Const adLockOptimistic = 3
Const adCmdText = &H1

Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

strPathtoTextFile = "C:\"

objConnection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
      "Data Source=" & strPathtoTextFile & ";" & _
      "Extended Properties=""text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited"""

strSql = "SELECT * FROM file.csv F1 " _
& " LEFT JOIN file2.csv F2 ON F1.[c1] = F2.[c1] "


objRecordset.Open strSql, objConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic,     adCmdText
MsgBox "Registros: " & objRecordset.RecordCount

Debug.Print Now


Do Until objRecordset.EOF
    Debug.Print "Name: " & objRecordset.Fields.Item("APOYO") & " Department: " & objRecordset.Fields.Item("O&D") & " Extension: " & objRecordset.Fields.Item("FECHA")
    objRecordset.MoveNext
Loop

''Tidy up
objRecordset.Close
objConnection.Close

End Sub
```